# Multiple Progress Bars in StatusStrip

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, progress-bar, statusstrip

I have an application where there can be several lengthy (minutes) tasks happening simultaneously in the background (i.e. the same task for different accounts, some accounts taking longer than others). I would like to show a progress bar and status text for each task in parallel. I supposed I could show that in a different window if there were many such accounts, but for now the scenario is just to have 2-4 accounts, therefore I'd like to show the progress bars in a StatusStrip at the bottom of the main form. I am thinking the StatusStrip should grow up and I would add ToolStripProgressBar's and ToolStripStatusLabel's one above the other dynamically, based on the number of accounts being processed at any given time. Is this possible? I was thinking of using a TableLayoutPanel inside the StatusStrip, but Visual Studio designer only allows very few components to be added to a StatusStrip. Is there any issue with me adding this programtically?

Comment: @RezaAghaei, why did you delete your answer, I was hoping to try it out soon

Comment: Because I didn't receive any response after I asked *Isn't it what you mean?* But if you are interested in the solution, I'll restore it again.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to try it before commenting on the answer. Thanks for restoring it. It is indeed what I meant.

Comment: Glad that it helped you :) You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it's not an intelligent UI design, but just for your information, you can add any control using [`ToolStripControlHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripcontrolhost(v=vs.110).aspx). Here is a simple example which lets you add multiple `StatusBar` controls in a single item of `StatusStrip` using code:

```
ToolStripControlHost host;
FlowLayoutPanel panel;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (panel == null)
    {
        panel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
        panel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
        panel.WrapContents = false;
        panel.AutoSize = true;
        panel.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
    }
    if (host == null)
    {
        host = new ToolStripControlHost(panel);
        this.statusStrip1.Items.Add(host);
    }
    panel.Controls.Add(new ProgressBar() { /* Value = new Random().Next(0, 100) */ });
}
```

[image]

**Note:** You also can extend `ToolStripControlHost` to provide design-time support, to do so take a look at [How to: Wrap a Windows Forms Control with ToolStripControlHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k5etstz(v=vs.110).aspx).