# How would I setup a StatusStrip with 2 StatusLabels below each other

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

So stuck on this little issue. I am trying to create a status strip with two labels, one below the other.

I've got the StatusStrip set as a TableLayout, with the row count set to 2, but no matter how I try configure the labels, they appear next to each other.

```
        '
        'StatusStrip1
        '
        Me.StatusStrip1.AutoSize = False
        CType(Me.StatusStrip1.LayoutSettings, TableLayoutSettings).RowCount = 2
        CType(Me.StatusStrip1.LayoutSettings, TableLayoutSettings).ColumnCount = 2
        Me.StatusStrip1.Items.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem() {Me.statusCyclePeriod, Me.statusLabel, Me.statusDuration})
        Dim cellPos As New TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(0, 0)
        CType(Me.StatusStrip1.LayoutSettings, TableLayoutSettings).SetCellPosition(Me.statusCyclePeriod, cellPos)
        cellPos = New TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(0, 1)
        CType(Me.StatusStrip1.LayoutSettings, TableLayoutSettings).SetCellPosition(Me.statusLabel, cellPos)
        cellPos = New TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(1, 1)
        CType(Me.StatusStrip1.LayoutSettings, TableLayoutSettings).SetCellPosition(Me.statusDuration, cellPos)
        Me.StatusStrip1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 426)
        Me.StatusStrip1.Name = "StatusStrip1"
        Me.StatusStrip1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(742, 47)
        Me.StatusStrip1.TabIndex = 7
        Me.StatusStrip1.Text = "StatusStrip1"
```

This is the modified generated code, to give an idea of what Im trying to do. 
I'll take any hints on the solution, c#/vb.net doesn't matter.

I know I am doing something silly or missing something stupidly obvious, but stuffed if i know.

Comment: That this code compiles is misleading, StatusStrip borrows the LayoutSettings class but does not in fact use the layout engine that TableLayoutPanel uses.  So the SetCellPosition() calls compile and run but StatusStrip just doesn't do anything with it.  Giving StatusStrip a custom layout engine is a pretty challenging task that is not very likely to come to a good end, you'd always first consider using a ToolStripControlHost.

Comment: I actually ended up throwing this idea out the window, but primarily due to time constraints, and ended up using a panel instead.
But still curious to see if any solution comes in for it.

Comment: Something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42028251/3110834)?

Comment: Thanks, that is actually exactly along the lines of what I was looking for. I knew it had to be something stupidly easy.